# Restart IBM Web Application Servers in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant, websphere, wsadmin

I am looking for a simple way to restart IBM Web Application Server from Jenkins. Right now there are two steps involved to restart servers in Jenkins.

1. Executing shell command
2. Invoke Ant

I feel that there should be a simpler way than above. Please share your tips, tricks, or tweaks. I do not have access to IBM Web Application Servers. But I do have access to IBM Web Sphere console.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If, according to the IBM documentation, you can restart the server from the command line, you should only need an "Execute shell" step.

Comment: Is there any way to restart server using REST services?

Comment: do you want to restart your whole Websphere instance (e.g. the whole WAS-service) or just a server/node on it?
Anyway, afaik there's not Rest-endpoint to do so. But you create yourself a python script which can be invoked by an external shell-command, and then it restarts the particular server/node.
Maybe you could also create a small app, which provides an endpoint to execute the shell-script itself again then. 
But if you can connect jenkins with the websphere via ssh, then do it better that way.